# Why overflow: hidden; not working on the "a"?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why my overflow:hidden not working on the "a". I really tried change width, height and set min/max height and width, but it didn't help.

I wanted that this red background has been trimmed because I'll be doing an animation.

the first time I have a problem with overflow:hidden;

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(255, 117, 117);
    z-index: 2;
}

.nav-menu ul {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -19%);
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.nav-menu ul li a {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu ul li a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 50px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;


}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projekty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: You need to set a defined width for `overflow` to work which is not in your current code.

Comment: First-of-all apply overflow:hidden to parent (ul) not to child (a) and even you apply overflow:hidden to your parent, your child have a width and height 100% of your parent. so overflow will no longer valuable in this case.  so make your child to have less width and height than your parent and then apply the overflow:hidden to your parent.

Comment: Also the `a` need to be inline block for overflow to take effect.

Comment: Of course, that may not do what you think it might - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GRQerPa